# Inline multine text

Tags: html, css

In HTML or using CSS, how can I produced this output

```
This is a text:  Very long text
                 that automatically gets wrapped
                 into multiple lines
```

Notice how the text wraps around and aligns on the left. I know I can use tables for the whole text, but I am looking for other ways. 
I am using a website generator where I only have control over the "Very long text..." part.

This is the html that I currently have

```
<i>This is a text:</i> 
<span itemprop="name">Very long text that automatically gets wrapped into multiple lines</span>
```

Comment: could you please post your HTML?

Comment: I just did. But I am afraid it's not close to what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping text requires it to have a fixed width (if you don't want all the space to be occupied by it, of course). You could have a try with this CSS

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

setting `inline-block` will allow it to have a `width` property, without setting it to `block`, as it will go on a newline. `vertical-align:top` is used to align the `<i>` tag at the top of the `<span>` text

Comment: Thanks. `inline-block` is the exact style I was looking for.